# Foundation / troble with HTML coding

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Can anyone help me with my product cart page? I can't find where I'm making a mistake.

```css
.body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.mainWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background: radial-gradient(#303d55, #2f3352);
}

.wrappen_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainBackground {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: url("../img/bgRectangl.png") left center no-repeat, url("../img/bgPhons.png") center center no-repeat, url("../img/layer-3-copy-2.png") center center no-repeat, url("../img/mainBg.png") center center no-repeat;
}

.productCard_block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 190px auto 0;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* LEFT SIDE */

.productCard_leftSide {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
}

.productCard_brendBlock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 184px;
  max-height: 75px;
  background-color: #272727;
  z-index: 2;
}

.productCard_brendBlock__imageBlock {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.productCard_brendBlock__imageBlock img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.sliderBlock {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 89px;
  margin-bottom: 46px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sliderBlock_items {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 403px;
}

.sliderBlock_items__itemPhoto {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.sliderBlock_items__showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}

.sliderBlock_items:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("../img/decorElements/DecorRectangle.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 4;
}

.sliderBlock_controls {
  width: 100%;
}

.sliderBlock_controls__navigatin {
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliderBlock_controls__wrapper {
  margin: 1% auto;
  width: 110px;
  height: 20px;
}

.sliderBlock_controls__arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #536dfe;
  transition: 300ms all;
  background-color: #0d2660;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sliderBlock_controls__arrow:hover {
  background-color: #536dfe;
}

.sliderBlock_controls__arrow i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  margin-top: -50%;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 300ms all;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sliderBlock_controls__arrowBackward {
  float: left;
}

.sliderBlock_controls__arrowForward {
  float: right;
}

.sliderBlock_positionControls {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}

.sliderBlock_positionControls__paginatorItem {
  float: left;
  width: 18px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: #D7D7D7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sliderBlock_positionControls__paginatorItem:first-child {
  margin-left: 31%;
}

.sliderBlock_positionControls__active {
  background-color: #536dfe;
}


/*   RIGHT SIDE */

.productCard_rightSide {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 34px;
  padding-left: 27px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
}

.block_specification {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #536dfe;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.block_specification__button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 7px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.block_specification:hover .block_specification__button__rotate {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
  -ms-transform: rotate(1turn);
  transform: rotate(1turn);
}

.block_specification:hover {
  color: #f1425d;
}

.block_specification__text {
  width: 30px;
  height: 11px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block_model {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #263238;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.block_name {
  width: 100%;
  color: #263238;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.block_name__mainName {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 29px;
}

.block_name__addName {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.block_product {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.block_product__advantagesProduct {
  width: 271px;
  height: 41px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  color: #646b6f;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.block_product__link {
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #536dfe;
}

.block_informationAboutDevice {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block_descriptionInformation {
  width: 304px;
  height: 104px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #263238;
}

.block_descriptionCharacteristic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
  transition: left, ease-out, 0.5s;
}

.block_descriptionCharacteristic__active {
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveCharackeristic {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes moveCharackeristic {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.block_specificationInformation_table {
  position: relative;
  height: 99.9%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block_specificationInformation_table tr {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.block_specificationInformation_table th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.block_specificationInformation_table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.block_rating {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 33px;
}

fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block_rating__stars {
  border: none;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label,
input[type="radio"]+label {
  margin: 0;
}

.block_rating__stars>input {
  display: none;
}

.block_rating__stars>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.block_rating__stars>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.block_rating__stars>label {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  float: right;
}


/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.block_rating__stars>input:checked~label,
.block_rating__stars:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.block_rating__stars:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #fccf47;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.block_rating__stars>input:checked+label:hover,
.block_rating__stars>input:checked~label:hover,
.block_rating__stars>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.block_rating__stars>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}

.block_rating__avarage {
  margin-left: 31px;
  color: #f1425d;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.block_rating__reviews {
  margin-left: 6px;
  color: #656c6f;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.block_price {
  margin-top: 29px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block_price__currency {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #f1425d;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.block_price__shipping {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #A2A9AD;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.radio_button {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.block_goodColor {
  margin-top: 29px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block_goodColor__allColors {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.block_goodColor__radio {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10% !important;
  background-color: #e8e6e3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio_button:checked+.block_goodColor__radio {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px rgba(83, 109, 254, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.block_goodColor__black {
  background-color: #3c383a;
}

.block_goodColor__silver {
  background-color: silver;
}

.text_specification {
  padding: 0;
  color: #37474f;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.block_quantity {
  position: relative;
  height: 46px;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.block_quantity span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block_quantity__chooseBlock {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block_quantity__number {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 52px;
  height: 46px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.block_quantity__number::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #403f40;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.block_quantity__number::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #403f40;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.block_quantity__number:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #403f40;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.block_quantity__number::placeholder {
  color: #403f40;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.block_quantity__button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 11px;
  font-size: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block_quantity__button:hover,
.block_quantity__button:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.block_quantity__button:hover:before,
.block_quantity__button:focus:before {
  color: #536dfe;
}

.block_quantity__up:before {
  content: "\f106";
  width: 11px;
  height: 6px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  color: #37474f;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.block_quantity__down:before {
  content: "\f107";
  width: 11px;
  height: 6px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  color: #37474f;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.button.button_addToCard {
  width: 147px;
  height: 46px;
  margin-top: 43px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #536dfe;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.button.button_addToCard:hover {
  background-color: #0d2660;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<main class="main">
  <div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="mainBackground clearfix">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column small-centered">
          <div class="productCard_block">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
                <div class="productCard_leftSide clearfix">
                  <div class="productCard_brendBlock">
                    <a class="productCard_brendBlock__imageBlock" href="#">
                      <img src="img/brtendsLogos/logo_sennheiser.png" alt="sennheiser">
                    </a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="sliderBlock">
                    <ul class="sliderBlock_items">
                      <li class="sliderBlock_items__itemPhoto sliderBlock_items__showing">
                        <img src="img/goods/item1/phones1.png" alt="headphones">
                      </li>
                      <li class="sliderBlock_items__itemPhoto">
                        <img src="img/goods/item1/phones2.png" alt="headphones">
                      </li>
                      <li class="sliderBlock_items__itemPhoto">
                        <img src="img/goods/item1/phones3.png" alt="headphones">
                      </li>
                      <li class="sliderBlock_items__itemPhoto">
                        <img src="img/goods/item1/phones4.png" alt="headphones">
                      </li>
                      <li class="sliderBlock_items__itemPhoto">
                        <img src="img/goods/item1/phones5.png" alt="headphones">
                      </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="sliderBlock_controls">
                      <div class="sliderBlock_controls__navigatin">
                        <div class="sliderBlock_controls__wrapper">
                          <div class="sliderBlock_controls__arrow sliderBlock_controls__arrowBackward">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="sliderBlock_controls__arrow sliderBlock_controls__arrowForward">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <ul class="sliderBlock_positionControls">
                        <li class="sliderBlock_positionControls__paginatorItem sliderBlock_positionControls__active"></li>
                        <li class="sliderBlock_positionControls__paginatorItem"></li>
                        <li class="sliderBlock_positionControls__paginatorItem"></li>
                        <li class="sliderBlock_positionControls__paginatorItem"></li>
                        <li class="sliderBlock_positionControls__paginatorItem"></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
                <div class="productCard_rightSide">
                  <div class="block_specification">
                    <div class="block_specification__specificationShow">
                      <i class="fa fa-cog block_specification__button block_specification__button__rotate" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <span class="block_specification__text">spec</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block_specification__informationShow hide">
                      <i class="fa fa-info-circle block_specification__button block_specification__button__jump" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <span class="block_specification__text">inform</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <p class="block_model">
                    <span class="block_model__text">Model: </span>
                    <span class="block_model__number">505795</span>
                  </p>

                  <div class="block_product">
                    <h2 class="block_name block_name__mainName">MOMENTUM<sup>&reg; </sup></h2>
                    <h2 class="block_name block_name__addName">Wireless Black</h2>

                    <p class="block_product__advantagesProduct">
                      Wireless headphones with integrated microphone
                    </p>

                    <div class="block_informationAboutDevice">

                      <div class="block_descriptionCharacteristic block_descriptionCharacteristic__disActive">
                        <table class="block_specificationInformation_table">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Characteristic</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Ear Coupling</td>
                            <td>Around Ear</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Transducer Principle</td>
                            <td>Dynamic, Closed-back</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Frequency Response</td>
                            <td>16Hz – 22kHz</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Sound Pressure Level (SPL)</td>
                            <td>113 dB (Passive: 1 kHz/1 Vrms)</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Total Harmonic Distortion (THD)</td>
                            <td>&lt;0.5% (1 kHz, 100 dB SPL)</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Volume Control</td>
                            <td>Earcup control when Bluetooth connected</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Microphone Type</td>
                            <td>Dual omni-directional microphone <br>(2 mic beam forming array)
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Cable / Connector</td>
                            <td>1.4m (Detachable) / 3.5mm Angled</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Weight</td>
                            <td>260g (9.17 oz)</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>


                      <div class="block_descriptionInformation">
                        <span>Peak performance with active noise cancelation. Sennheiser's new MOMENTUM Wireless
                                                - Closed circumauralheadphone featuring <a class="block_product__link"
                                                                                           href="#">Bluetooth<sup>&reg;</sup></a>  wireless technology and NoiseGard Hybrid active noise cancelation
                                                </span>
                      </div>

                      <div class="block_rating">
                        <fieldset class="block_rating__stars">
                          <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Good - 4 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Above average - 3.5 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Average - 3 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
                          <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
                        </fieldset>

                        <span class="block_rating__avarage">4.25</span>
                        <span class="block_rating__reviews">(153 reviews)</span>

                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-6 small-12 column">
                          <div class="block_price">
                            <p class="block_price__currency">$499.95</p>
                            <p class="block_price__shipping">Shipping and taxes extra</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="block_quantity">
                            <span class="text_specification">Quantity</span>
                            <div class="block_quantity__chooseBlock">
                              <input class="block_quantity__number" name="quantityNumber" type="text" min="1" value="1">
                              <button class="block_quantity__button block_quantity__up"></button>
                              <button class="block_quantity__button block_quantity__down"></button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="large-6 small-12 end column">
                          <div class="block_goodColor">
                            <span class="text_specification">Choose your colors:</span>
                            <div class="block_goodColor__allColors">
                              <input type="radio" name="colorOfItem" class="radio_button" id="radioColor" checked/>
                              <label for="radioColor" class="block_goodColor__radio block_goodColor__black"></label>
                              <input type="radio" name="colorOfItem" class="radio_button" id="radioColor2" />
                              <label for="radioColor2" class="block_goodColor__radio block_goodColor__silver"></label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <button class="button button_addToCard">
                                                        Add to Cart
                                                    </button>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

For clarification, I'll show you two photos. On the first photo as it now looks, and on the second, how it should look like

[[image: problem]] Picture with problem[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqNTE.png)
[[image: How it should look like]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD9GX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the class `clearfix` to the `block_rating` div, because the floating elements in that div are causing the preceding floating elements to stack up next to them.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgXqqd

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting such great info to troubleshoot with, but without a little bit more it'll be hard for me to help. Have you thought of installing a chrome extension like Pesticide? It'll help you actually see outlines of what is where so you can figure out what happened. You can right click on elements and left click inspect to then see them in Chrome Developer Tools and actually look at what CSS is applying to them. You can then add in-line styles to style them manually while the window it open to try out solutions before returning to your CSS document and finalizing them (by adding them more permanently). Take caution when using !important though as it's kind of bringing a gun to a knife fight imho. Good luck and feel free to post screens of your site once pesticide is running and drawing boxes.

Comment: Thanks for advice but it didn't help https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/bRVdyR I don't see where is problem

Comment: No worries! Glad you found an answer : ).

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my two cents... when you use any grid framework (Foundation in this case, but could be any other), please try to achieve all the layout just using the grid... when you put between grid hierarchy other divs with margin, padding, sizing, weird things can happen (like this bug).

As far as I can see, **right side layout** can be solved just using the grid, would be something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column medium-6"> Stars goes here </div>
    <div class="column medium-6"> Point rating and review count </div>
</div>
<div class="row price-holder">
    <div class="column medium-6"> Price goes here </div>
    <div class="column medium-6"> Color selector </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column medium-6"> Quantity selector </div>
    <div class="column medium-6"> Add to cart button </div>
</div>
```

BTW, I added the class `price-holder`, where you could add a top-padding to make some space, if you want it that way (no need of additional elements). If you want to keep the layout on mobile, please use `small-6` instead of `medium-6`.

You could use additional containers *inside the columns*, so you can style elements like pricing and so, although you could add the classes to the columns, as long as you don't add rules for width, margin or padding (again, weird things could happen).

Hope this helps.